# Request.URL doubles query string parameters?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms, asp.net-4.0, formsauthentication

I request a URL like this:

```
http://mylocalsite/virtual/page.aspx?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3
```

I'm using `FormsAuthentication` and am unauthenticated, so I'm redirected. This is what the browser location bar shows:

```
http://mylocalsite/virtual/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/virtual/page.aspx?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3
```

In the PageLoad event of login.aspx I try to inspect the URL two ways:

```
Dim example1 as String = Request.Url

Dim example2 as String = Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & Request.Url.Authority & Request.RawUrl
```

This is what I get:

```
' Example 1
http://mylocalsite/virtual/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/virtual/page.aspx?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3&var1=1&var2=2&var3=3

' Example 2 - is URLEncoded
http://mylocalsite/virtual/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fvirtual%2fpage.aspx%3fvar1%3d1%26var2%3d2%26var3%3d3%26var1%3d1%26var2%3d2%26var3%3d3
```

Why is my query string doubling up in both of these examples?

Comment: IIS = 7.5.7600.16385 on localhost (Windows 7 SP1) or live site (Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1) and Application Pool = .NET v4.0 Integrated pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by design so you have access to those querystring parameters during login.  Those parameters must also be preserved for redirect post-login too - so they are url encoded as well. See the [Anatomy of Forms Authentication ReturnUrl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2008/01/24/anatomy-of-forms-authentication-return-url.aspx) for a more detailed explanation.